# Finding duplicate records from table and deleting all but one with latest date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table structure like given below

```
FileId      FileName          CreatedBy       CreationDate

-------    ----------        -----------      ------------
File1_1    File1                User1        2014/09/12 17:10:49
File1_2    File1                User1        2014/09/11 17:45:49
File2_1    File2                User2        2014/05/11 17:45:22
File2_3    File2                User1        2014/08/11 17:47:22
```

I want to write a query that will get files with their names who have duplicated entries and delete all entries but the one with latest date..
For example in current example it will delete the record with id `File1_2` and `File2_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a `SELECT` query which identifies the rows you want deleted.

```sql
SELECT y.CreatedBy, y.FileId, y.FileName, y.CreationDate
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE
    y.CreationDate <  
        DMax(
            "CreationDate",
            "YourTable",
            "FileName='" & y.FileName & "'"
            );
```

After you verify that query identifies the correct rows, convert it to a `DELETE` query.

```sql
DELETE
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE
    y.CreationDate <  
        DMax(
            "CreationDate",
            "YourTable",
            "FileName='" & y.FileName & "'"
            );
```

Comment: One more question If instead of deleting the entire row If I want to Update a "Yes/No" type field how can I do it.. I am posting the query I am trying ..

Comment: UPDATE Files
SET Locked=True
FROM Files AS y
WHERE
    y.CreationDate <  
        DMax(
            "CreationDate",
            "Files",
            "FileName='" & y.FileName & "'"
            );

Comment: Access doesn't expect `FROM` in an `UPDATE` statement.  Try it this way: `UPDATE Files AS y SET y.Locked=True WHERE y.CreationDate < DMax("CreationDate", "Files", "FileName='" & y.FileName & "'" );`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE TableA 
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(creationDate) as dt, FileId FROM TableA
GROUP by FileId
HAVING count(*) > 1
) T
where A.FileId = T.FileId
and A.dt < T.dt
```

Comment: says some syntax error in FROM clause the table name is "Files"